# Error moving files in shell for-loop

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am using the following shell code to move files from one location to another:

```
for i in [ test1 test2 test3]
do
  mv /home/usr/enabler/$i/*  /home/bin/enabler/consolidate
  echo "moved successfully!!!"
done
```

Running in the bash shell I get the error `"Illegal file pattern: Unclosed character class near index 1"`. I want the loop to go to each folder `test1`, `test2`, `test3` and move all files present in `test1`,  `test2`, `test3` in destination folder.

Comment: The square brackets don't seem to be at all useful here, why did you put those?  Also take care to properly quote your variables.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: single line: `mv /home/usr/enabler/{test1,test2,test3}/*  /home/bin/enabler/consolidate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your script that way:

```
for i in test1 test2 test3
do
  mv /home/usr/enabler/"$i"/*  /home/bin/enabler/consolidate
  echo "moved successfully!!!"
done
```

This is exactly that you want!!